# Where are pgAdmin logs for failed server connections?

Tags: postgresql, authentication, pgadmin

How do you find out WHY the connecting Server failed? There must be log the reports why it fails, but I can’t find it in the pgAdmin3 program. I cannot get PpgAdmin connection to the server.

Below See Screen Shot below.

[image: What I see When it Fails]

[image: New Server Registration Screen Shot Click here if doesn't upload]

Please note I am beginner in SQL databases—so I don’t know a lot yet. There must be a way in the program to find out WHY it failed.

Without any clues to why it failed, it is very hard to diagnose the issue. Which is the focus of this question.

I tried a re-install of Postgresql, I discovered a install error that happen the first time but I missed noticing the first time. [Install Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iI0B2.png)

Also found install logs at C:\PostgreSQL\logs\PostgreSQL-installLog Which lead me to event viewer and I found these errors.

[Event View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WuxHi.png)
**Anyone have idea of what they mean or more IMPORTANTLY how to solve this issue?**

Comment: Now added. Click on New Server Registration Shot

Comment: What happens if you try to connect using the command line `psql`?

Comment: If fails too, It trying to connect to localhost and it states connection is refused. I've been trying to change .conf files to go to a different IP Address--without success yet.

Comment: What is the **exact** error message you get from `psql` ([edit] your question, do not add additional information as comments)

Comment: So, do you have a Postgres server on the computer where you run `psql`? You should try to connect to the server you are trying to reach from pgAdmin (e.g. `psql -h some_server`)